# Obtaining random number from a mixture of two normal distributions

Tags: r

I want to sample from mixed normal distribution, first one is $N(1,2)$, second one is $N(5,4)$. I used `rnorm(100, c(mean=c(1,5), sd=c(2,4)))`. Is this correct?

The problem I am trying to solve is sampling from the 2 distribution above, first one with 75%, second one with 25%.  Am I on the right track?

**Edit:**  I will rewrite the problem for clearance, with easier numbers. :)

I want to sample from $N(0,1)$ with 70% probability, and $N(100,10)$ with 30% probability.
Of course, that's just for sake of discussion, the actually distribution I am working with is n(21, 3.3), n(26,4).

Comment: how about `c(rnorm(75, 1, 5), rnorm(25, 2, 4)`

Comment: @David - you might want to make an answer out of the comment, so you can get "answer" credit for it.  Also, it should be rnorm(75,1,2) and rnorm(25,5,4).

Comment: ^ +1. If you want to permute this result, install `gregmisc` and use the `permute` function.

Comment: @David: The 75, and 25 will give me exactly 75 and 25 samples for each distribution.  But the 75% and 25% are just the probabilities getting each, not exactly those numbers.

Comment: @Arun: can I avoid using any package?

Comment: @Arun `permute` is a trivial wrapper of R built-in `sample` function, so you need no external packages.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to sample unequally (with probability 0.7 and 0.3) from two gaussians with parameters $(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$, then you can probably try something like that:

```
n <- 100
yn <- rbinom(n, 1, .7)
# draw n units from a mixture of N(0,1) and N(100,3^2)
s <- rnorm(n, 0 + 100*yn, 1 + 2*yn)
```

In fact, this is one of the illustrations provided in *Modern Applied Statistics with S*, by Venables and Ripley (Springer, 2002; §5.2, pp. 110-111).

With different parameters, you can use an `ifelse` expression to select the mean and SD according to the binomial sequence given in `yn`, e.g. `rnorm(n, mean=ifelse(yn, 21, 26), sd=ifelse(yn, 3.3, 4))`. (No need to cast `yn` to a logical with `as.logical`.)

Comment: elegant. impressed! :)

Comment: @chl: I am looking at it, I don't see that page.

Comment: @mike My first example is exactly the same as the code you wrote: as the two theoretical distributions have the same mean but different variance, they only varied the SD, which defaults to 3 when the $i$th Bernoulli event (which has probability 0.05 of occurring) equals 1, 1 otherwise.

Comment: @chl: I am a little confused.  Could you explain what the ifelse() does in here?  I am guessing it matches up mu1 with sd1, mu2 with sd2?

Comment: @chl: Actually, can you explain what binom(n,size=3,prob=0.7) does?  How can you do size=3, meaning you are picking from numbers 1,2,3, isn't binomial just 0's and 1's?  Thanks a lot, you are a great help!

Comment: @mike (a) `ifelse(yn, 21, 26)` gives a vector of 21 (if `yn==1`) and 26's (if `yn==0`). (b) `binom(n,size=1,prob=0.7)` yields $n$ random 0/1 deviates drawn from a ${\cal B}(n, 0.7)$ (binomial with probability of observing a success, or 1, of 0.7).

Comment: @chl: I definitely need to look at what you said and understand it, it worked well.  The true mixture mean 0.72*21+0.28*26, and the mean from simulation have been very close. :)  But why the true variance is (0.72*3.3)^2+(0.28*4)^2=6.9, but my simulation gives around 17.39.

Comment: @chl: how would you carry out a simulation with this mixed variance: (0.72*3.3)^2+(0.28*4)^2, the sd probability simply don't add up!

Comment: @chi your answer is nice and I have learned from it, but I should note that mine is as much as 2x faster (at least on my machine): `n <- 1000000; p <- 0.7; print('chi'); system.time({yn <- rbinom(n, 1, p);  rnorm(n,0+100*yn, 1+2*yn)}); print('David'); system.time({yn <- runif(n, 0, 1) > p;  c(rnorm(sum(yn),0, 1), rnorm(sum(!yn), 100,2))})`

Comment: Mike, for your particular values the expression merely becomes `s <- rnorm(n, 21 + 5*yn, 3.3 + 0.7*yn)`  Here, $5=26-21$ and $0.7=4-3.3$.

Comment: @whuber: I suppose you are referring to my mixed variance question above? why 26-21 and 4-3.3?  That does not give me mixed variance (0.72*3.3)^2+(0.28*4)^2=6.6899.

Comment: @whuber: nevermind, I got what you are saying.  But var(s)=4.3 is still NOT close to (0.72*3.3)^2+(0.28*4)^2=6.6899, what is wrong?

Comment: @David I didn't see your update (+1) when I posted my reply. Per Elvis's suggestion, you may want to resample the resulting vector.

Comment: @mike If you want to get the variance of the combined sample, you need to account for the different location parameters (or their estimates) as well.

Comment: The formula you are using, Mike--a sum of squares of weighted standard deviations--does not correspond to anything useful.  It certainly is not a variance.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish the goal of sampling from an uneven mixture of distributions, the most straightforward approach is to sample separately, in proportion to the desired ratio:

```
 p <- 0.70 #P(from N(mu1, sd1)) 
 n.samps <- 10000
 mu1 <- 0
 sd1 <- 1
 mu2 <- 100
 sd2 <- 10

 x <- vector()
 for(i in 1:n.samps){
    b <- runif(1, 0, 1)
    if(b < p){
       x[i] <- rnorm(1, mu1, sd1)
     } else { 
       x[i] <- rnorm(1, mu2, sd2)
     }
   }
```

this can be done ~50 x faster:

```
 binary <- runif(n.samps, 0, 1) > p
 x <- c(rnorm(sum(binary), 1, 2), rnorm(sum(!binary), 5, 4)
```

then to draw a sample:

```
sample(x, 1)
```

or to reshuffle:

```
x <- sample(x, n.samp)
```

Comment: I edit the question, hopefully, it's clear now.  I have seen packages doing mixture normal, my guess is you can't do it with one line in rnorm()?  Or maybe it is very complicated?

Comment: A defect of this method is that `x` is ordered, you would need to shuffle it with `sample(x, length(x))`. The value of `sum(binary)` could be generated directly as `s <- rbinom(1,n,p)` and of course the value of `sum(!binary)` is `n-s`.

Comment: @elvis thanks for pointing that out; the for loop output is shuffled, I just tried to vectorize after seeing chi's answer.